How to make a table of 2 columns from a list?
I have a list var words=['ac', 'bd', 'bf','uy','ca'];
I want to form a table of 2 columns listing all these words one after another from left to right.
The result table should be
<table id="wordTable">
 <tr>
   <td>ac </td>   <td>bd </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>bf </td>   <td>uy </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ca </td>   <td> </td>
 </tr>

</table> 

This javascript code does not work
function showWords(){
  row_Index=0;
  for (const myWord of words)
  {
    if (row_Index==0){
     document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML +="<tr>";      
     document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML += "<td>"+ myWord +"</td>";
     }
     else if (row_Index==1){
     document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML += "<td>"+ myWord +"</td>";

     document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML +="</tr>";        
     }
     else if (row_Index==2){
        row_Index=0;
     }
     row_Index++;
  }
}

How to create that table from the list?
Also, how to clear all the rows and columns of the table?
document.getElementById("wordTable").clear();

or document.getElementById("wordTable").remove();
don't work

You could do it with a combination of .reduce() and .map like this:


var words=['ac', 'bd', 'bf','uy','ca'];

const html=arr2tbl(2);
document.getElementById("wordTable").innerHTML=html;
console.log(html);

function arr2tbl(ncols){
 let j=0;
 return words.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
 if(i%ncols==0)a.push([]);
   a.at(-1).push(c);
   return a;
  },[]).map(r=>"<tr>"+r.map(c=>`<td id="val${++j}">${c}</td>`).join("")+"</tr>").join("\n");
}
<table id="wordTable"></table>



The function parameter ncols can be set to any value. Here the value 2 fulfills OP's requirements.
An id attribute can be added quite easily as shown above. Valid ids should always start with a letter and not a number. I chose the prefix val here but any other alphabetic prefix should also do the job.

Yes, I can dynamically change the numbers of columns easily

I want each word to have a uniqueID so that I can format them dynamicly. How to add id from 1 to 5 to "td" for each word? for example, "ac" will have id 1,  "bd" will have id 2 etc?

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var words = ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'];
                var table = document.getElementById("wordTable");
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 2) {
                    var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
                    var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
                    cell1.textContent = words[i];
                    cell2.textContent = (i + 1 < words.length) ? words[i + 1] : '';
                    row.appendChild(cell1);
                    row.appendChild(cell2);
                    table.appendChild(row);
                }
            });

            <div id="wordTable">
            </div>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.


var words = ['ac', 'bd', 'bf', 'uy', 'ca'];
var table = document.getElementById('wordTable');

// Clear the existing table content
table.innerHTML = '';

var row, cell1, cell2;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 2) {
  row = table.insertRow();
  cell1 = row.insertCell();
  cell1.textContent = words[i] || '';
  cell2 = row.insertCell();
  cell2.textContent = words[i + 1] || '';
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
<table id="wordTable">
</table>



